# IE7 :: SCRIPT1014: Invalid character

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

I have a webpage that I recently changed that works great on all browsers except for IE7.  On IE7 I see the following:

> SCRIPT1014: Invalid character  blah.html, line 1 character 1

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I've reviewed the code several times and nothing sticks out.  I know its a javascript error, but I can't pinpoint where.

The frustrating part is not knowing where to look (line 1 character 1) and the error being vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Error in a Nutshell

The problem was a javascript error inside a string in a call to `window.setTimeout`.

### More Detail

The string in `window.setTimeout([string], [int])` is executed as an eval, so it caused a javascript error during execution, which for me happened to be during the window onload event.

**Why did the error say "Invalid Character"?**

Because I used a `#` instead of a `$` to start a jquery command.  The javascript compiler didn't know what to do with `#` so it threw an error.

**Why did the error report being on line 1 character 1?**

Since the string in the `window.setTimeout` is executed as an eval, the error was reported on line 1 character 1 - which finally makes sense!

**Sample html to replicate issue**

Here is a sample page I created demonstrating the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            window.setTimeout("#('#sdfl');", 1000);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Resolution

I accidentally used a `#` instead of a `$` for a jquery command in the eval string.  This is actually legacy code, so I refactored it to call a specific function rather than invoke an eval on a string (**evil**) so it now looks more like:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
      $('#sdfl');
   }, 1000);
```

Note that with this change that finding the original error would've been much easier as it would've given a specific line and character number relative to the page rather than the eval string.